# Make a different image appear when hovering over a div

Tags: html, css

I've tried many methods on how to resolve this issue, but I can't seem to find a solution, so it's time to ask help from more experienced people.
Basically what I want is for an image to change when I hover over its 'div' (the box) that the img is in. Have a look at the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>

            body {
            background: grey;
            }

            #box {
                margin: 0 auto;
                width:  300px;
                height: 300px;
                background: blue
            }
            #box img {
                display: block;
                margin: 0 auto;
                padding-top: 75px;
            }
        </style>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#">
            <div id="box">
                <img src="registration_icon_white.png" onmouseover="src='registration_icon_black.png'" onmouseout="'registration_icon_black.png'">
            </div>
        </a>
    </body>
```

(the images are the same, just with different colors)

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: can you use javascript or better yet jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just put the image in the background of the `div`.

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/yofabanavu/edit?html,css,output)

```
<div id="box"></div>
```

[More on CSS background](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background)

```
#box {
  background: url("registration_icon_black.png");
  height: 500px;
}

#box:hover{
  background: url("registration_icon_white.png");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not specifying what src to are assigning the URL too. You would need to use `this.src='URL'` in the onmouseover and onmouseout events.

Here is a link about the `this` keyword:
[How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: To have it change when hovering over the div "box" move the onmouseover and onmouseout events to the div and have the code they run target the img tag.

`<div id="box" onmouseover="this.querySelector('img').src='registration_icon_black.png'" onmouseout="this.querySelector('img').src='registration_icon_white.png'">
      <img title="some title" src="registration_icon_white.png">
    </div>`

Answer (score 0):

Try with `this.src`:

```
    <div id="box">              
      <img title="some title" src="registration_icon_white.png" 
           onmouseover="this.src='registration_icon_black.png'"
           onmouseout="this.src='registration_icon_white.png'">
    </div>
```

Comment: That's a step into the right direction, thanks.

Do you also by any chance know how I can trigger this by hovering over the box instead of the image itself?

Comment: You will need javascript (or JQuery) to do that.